# How to prevent loading cursor during jQuery AJAX Get Requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm firing off two AJAX requests through jQuery on page load.  They are GET requests.

In Chrome, I am finding that the page still indicates it is loading through cursor and status text in bottom left of the window until the AJAX requests have completed.

Ideally, I would like the status text and cursor to not be effected by the AJAX requests at all.

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent this?

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/createsite/CheckDnsKey?site_id='+site_id+'&r='+Math.random(100000000),
        success:function(data){updateDomainDisplay(KEY_INFO_COMPLETE,data)},
        error:showDomainError
});             
$.ajax({
        url:'/createsite/CheckDnsKeyStatus?site_id='+site_id+'&r='+Math.random(100000000),
        success:function(data){updateDomainDisplay(STATUS_COMPLETE,data)},
        error:showDomainError
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is something you have control over. As far as your code is concerned I would improve it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/createsite/CheckDnsKey',
    data: { site_id: site_id },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) { 
        updateDomainDisplay(KEY_INFO_COMPLETE,data); 
    },
    error: showDomainError
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is over a year old but just in case anyone comes across this like I did; a possible solution would be to fire the $.ajax({}); event within a setTimeout:

```
myAjaxRequest = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/createsite/CheckDnsKey',
        data: { site_id: site_id },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) { 
            updateDomainDisplay(KEY_INFO_COMPLETE,data); 
        },
        error: showDomainError
    });
};

setTimeout(function () { myAjaxRequest(); }, 100);
```